# Grails and hibernate session, save to database on exception

Tags: hibernate, session, exception, grails, transactions

I'm using Grails framework.

Want to save something to database on failure (after `RuntimeException` is thrown). Let's say I have something like this in one of transactional services:

```
try {
   throw new RuntimeException()
} catch(Exception ex) {
   new FatalErrorDomainObject().save()
}
```

Current version will fail because session is set to rollback.

I tried to solve this problem in multiple ways and what I found so far is:

`.withTransaction` - will not work because will bind transaction to current session

`.withSession` - will not work because will just reuse existing session

`.withNewSession` - alone will not work because it will create new session in same thread (same thread = same db connection, so it will fail with SQL exception)

The only working solution I found so far is to create new thread and new hibernate session. Is it really the only (and the right) way to accomplish this?

```
public static void syncSession(Closure job) {
    // Checking environment in production code it's not very elegant but thanks to this it's transparent
    // for all tests and makes them DRY.
    if(Environment.current == Environment.TEST) {
        job.call()
    }
    Thread t = new Thread({
        DomainObject.withNewSession {
            job.call()
        }
    })
    t.start()
    t.join()
}
```

Usage:

```
try {
   throw new RuntimeException()
} catch(Exception ex) {
   syncSession {
      new FatalErrorDomainObject().save()
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution is better but I thought of giving you this suggestion anyway: call `new FatalErrorDomainObject().save()` in a separate transaction **before** the rest of your logic and at the end of it, before the commit, delete the FatalErrorDomainObject. Something like this:

```
def fatalError = new FatalErrorDomainObject()
FatalErrorDomainObject.withTransaction { status ->
    fatalError.save()
}
doSomethingThatMightThrowRuntimeException()
FatalErrorDomainObject.get(fatalError.id).delete()
```

Comment: This error object is used to notify that something wrong happen, It would mark that all invocations are bad (propagate error via email for example) and then I would silently remove it. Won't work in my case but thanks for suggestion.